# R Script - Derived all combinations

Tags: r, join, combinations, plyr

I have a dataset similar to the one provide below, and I am trying to create an output dataset which includes all combinations of two columns.

-

For example, I have the following input data set:

```
Region, Variable, Amount

Asia, Car, 15000

Asia, House, 175000

Asia, Truck, 200000

......
```

I would like to obtain the following output dataset:

```
Region, Variable1, Variable2, Amount1, Amount2

Asia, Car, Car, 15000, 15000

Asia, Car, House, 15000, 175000

Asia, Car, Truck, 175000, 200000

Asia, House, Car, 175000, 15000

......
```

After some preliminary research, I found that the library(plyr) or the expand.grid may be of help, but I cannot seem to figure out how to implement this. I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this `merge(df, df, by="Region")` give what you want?

Comment: `tidyr::crossing(df, setNames(df[-1], paste0(names(df)[-1], '_2')))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `merge`

```
input <- read.table(text = "Region Variable Amount
                    Asia Car 15000
                    Asia House 175000
                    Asia Truck 200000", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

merge(input, input, by = "Region", suffixes = c(".1", ".2"))

  Region Variable.1 Amount.1 Variable.2 Amount.2
1   Asia        Car    15000        Car    15000
2   Asia        Car    15000      House   175000
3   Asia        Car    15000      Truck   200000
4   Asia      House   175000        Car    15000
5   Asia      House   175000      House   175000
6   Asia      House   175000      Truck   200000
7   Asia      Truck   200000        Car    15000
8   Asia      Truck   200000      House   175000
9   Asia      Truck   200000      Truck   200000
```

Comment: Thank you zyurnaidi. I only just realized that this was merely a JOIN on Region and coded an approach very similar to yours!